# What is the correct way to explain what an abbreviation stands for?

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct way to explain what the abbreviation in this sentence stands for:

> Also known as the “OLI” framework – standing for Ownership, Location
>   and Internalization, it conceptualizes the core reasons for a firm to
>   invest in a foreign country, dividing them into three sources of
>   advantages.
>
> Also known as the “OLI” framework – standing for 'Ownership',
>   'Location' and 'Internalization', it conceptualizes the core reasons
>   for a firm to invest in a foreign country, dividing them into three
>   sources of advantages.

or

> Also known as the “OLI” framework – standing for ownership, location
>   and internalization, it conceptualizes the core reasons for a firm to
>   invest in a foreign country, dividing them into three sources of
>   advantages (Neary, 2009).

If none of the 3 options is correct, please explain what the proper way is.

Comment: There is no *correct* way—it's purely a matter of style. More often than not, an abbreviation is put in parentheses *after* its long form. For example: *ownership, location, and internationalization (OLI)*. Also, unless the long form is a proper noun (I don't know in this case), the individual words would not start with capital letters.